# Can Response not return an integer value in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, request, scrapy-request

In order to find out how many bills has each member of parliament has their signature, I'm trying to write a scraper on the members of parliament which works with 3 layers:

1. **Accessing the link for each MP from the list**
2. **From (1) accessing the page with information including the bills the MP has a signature on**
3. **From (3) accessing the page where the bill proposals with MP's signature is shown, count them, assign their number to ktsayisi variable**  (problem occurs here)

At the last layer, I'm trying to return the number of bills by counting by the relevant xss selector by means of len() function. But apparently I can't assign the returned number from  (3) to a value to be eventually yielded.

**Scrapy returns just the link accessed rather than the number that I want the function to return. Why is it so? Can't I write a statement like X = Request(url,callback = function) where the defined function used in Response can iterate an integer? How can I fix it?**

I want a number to be in the place of these statements yielded : <GET [https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/Milletvekilleri/KanunTeklifiUyeninImzasiBulunanTeklifler?donemKod=27&sicil=UqVZp9Fvweo=>](https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/Milletvekilleri/KanunTeklifiUyeninImzasiBulunanTeklifler?donemKod=27&sicil=UqVZp9Fvweo=%3E)

Thanks in advance.

[image: What is yielded]

'''

```
from scrapy import Spider

from scrapy.http import Request

class MvSpider(Spider):
    name = 'mv'
    allowed_domains = ['tbmm.gov.tr']  #website of the parliament
    start_urls = ['https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/Milletvekilleri/liste'] #the link which has the list of MPs


def parse(self, response):
    
    mv_linkler = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-8"]/a/@href').getall()

    for link in mv_linkler:
        mutlak_link = response.urljoin(link)  #absolute url


        yield Request(mutlak_link, callback = self.mv_analiz)

def mv_analiz(self, response): #function to analyze the MP

        kteklif_link_path = response.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'İmzası Bulunan Kanun Teklifleri')]/@href").get()
        kteklif_link = response.urljoin(kteklif_link_path)
        
        ktsayisi = int(Request(kteklif_link, callback = self.kt_say)) #the value of the number of bill proposals to be requested

def kt_say(self,response):

    kteklifler = response.xpath("//tr[@valign='TOP']")

    return len(kteklifler)
```

'''

Comment: `Request` doesn't work as you expect - it sends url on special list which will later use this url to get data from server - and `Request` doesn't wait for result so it can't give you this value. You have to send all data to `kt_say` and inside `kt_say` you have to add new value and `yield` all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, furas's explanation pretty much covers why and I don't have anything to add, you need to do something like this:

```py
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class MvSpider(Spider):
    name = 'mv'
    allowed_domains = ['tbmm.gov.tr']  #website of the parliament
    start_urls = ['https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/Milletvekilleri/liste'] #the link which has the list of MPs

    def parse(self, response):
        mv_linkler = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-8"]/a/@href').getall()

        for link in mv_linkler:
            mutlak_link = response.urljoin(link)  #absolute url

            yield Request(mutlak_link, callback=self.mv_analiz)

    def mv_analiz(self, response): #function to analyze the MP
        kteklif_link_path = response.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'İmzası Bulunan Kanun Teklifleri')]/@href").get()
        kteklif_link = response.urljoin(kteklif_link_path)
        item = {}
        req = Request(kteklif_link, callback=self.kt_say) #the value of the number of bill proposals to be requested
        req.meta['item'] = item
        yield req

    def kt_say(self, response):
        kteklifler = response.xpath("//tr[@valign='TOP']")
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['ktsayisi'] = len(kteklifler)
        yield item
```

Comment: Could you further explain what happened in item = response.meta['item'] ?  I checked the documentation but couldn't grasp it.

Comment: I'm passing `item={}` to kt_say then assigning it to item. If for example in mv_analiz item was `item={'some': 'thing'}` so in kt_say we would've yield something like: `{'some': 'thing', 'ktsayisi': 7}`. Try playing with it.