# Give variable to callback function with yield

Tags: python, scrapy

in Scrapy

I have two function at first `parse()` is called and `parse_each()` is called in `parse()`

```
class UtamapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=each_url, callback=self.parse_each)

    def parse_each(self,response):
```

Now, I want to pass some additional parameter to parse_each.
So, what I want to do is like this.

```
class UtamapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=each_url, callback=self.parse_each(99)) #example pass value `99`

    def parse_each(self,response,myvalue):
        print(myvalue) # 99
```

I am afraid it might be impossible, but is there any good way to pass the additional data to callback function??

Comment: There are good answers, I just wanted to mention that you can use `meta`. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327633/can-response-not-return-an-integer-value-in-scrapy/70330744#70330744).

Comment: I agree `meta` is the way to go in my opinion. I shared an example with your code below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70397911/8969084

Comment: Meta works well and what I wanted  thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right approach to share values between children requests and parse functions is to pass this in the `meta` attribute from the Request object, which accepts a dict that will be copied to the Response object to be created. For instance:

```
class UtamapSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=each_url, callback=self.parse_each, meta={'myvalue': 99})

    def parse_each(self,response,myvalue):
        print(response.meta['myvalue'])) # 99
```

From the docs:

> meta (dict) – the initial values for the Request.meta attribute. If
> given, the dict passed in this parameter will be shallow copied.

More info on https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta

Answer (score 0):

the canonical way would be to use a lambda

```
callback=lambda response:self.parse_each(response, 99)
```

Comment: I am not familliar with  lambda of python, though I will learn this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cb_kwargs` argument of the `Request` class such as below.

```
class UtamapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=each_url, cb_kwargs={“myvalue”: 99}, callback=self.parse_each) #example pass value `99`

    def parse_each(self,response,myvalue):
        print(myvalue) # 99
```

Comment: THank you for your comment, `meta` works almost same but I would appreciate your propotion.